# How to change the start position in Chessboard.js?

Tags: javascript, chess, chessboard.js

I am using the code given in the website https://chessboardjs.com/examples#5000.
Here, when I try to change the start position in the config, all the pieces snap back to the intial position when any piece is moved. I also tried using game.load('fen'), but it gives the same result. Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

I want to change the starting position, like in the cases of puzzles where only some pieces are there but all the usual chess rules are followed.

I tried using game.load('fen') and also change the 'position' in 'configs'.

Comment: https://chessboardjs.com/examples#1002

Comment: @jabaa I mentioned in the question that changing the config properties doesn't work.

Comment: In that case, either the documentation is wrong or you found a bug. In both cases, you should ask the developer. https://github.com/oakmac/chessboardjs/issues/139 seems to be a 5 year old bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out later myself. The problem is that chessboard.js and chess.js use different types of FENs. In chessboard.js, the FEN is simply

`'rnbqkbnr/ppp1pppp/8/3p4/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR'`

whereas in chess.js, there are additional elements at the end:
`'rnbqkbnr/ppp1pppp/8/3p4/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq d6 0 2'`

To achieve the desired result, change the position in the configs to the chessboard.js one

```
var config = {
                draggable: true,
                position: 'rnbqkbnr/ppp1pppp/8/3p4/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR',
                onDragStart: onDragStart,
                onDrop: onDrop,
                onSnapEnd: onSnapEnd
            }
```

and load the chess.js board with its own FEN

```
var game = new Chess()
game.load('rnbqkbnr/ppp1pppp/8/3p4/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq d6 0 2')
```

I hope this solution helps someone in the future!